# Гиперболический арктангес в С++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Здравствуйте, задание у меня вот такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывести надо: значение аргумента, значение функции, количество просуммированных членов ряда и расчет функции стандартными средствами с++.

Собственно код я написал но как этот arth посчитать? У меня он его просто не считает... Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int max = 500;
    double Xstart, Xend, dX, sum, e, element, x;
    int c;

    cin >> Xstart >> Xend >> dX >> e;
    for ( x = Xstart; (Xend - x)>-0.00001; x += dX)
    {
        c = 0;
        element = 1;
        sum = 0;
        for (int n = 0; fabs(element)>e && n <= max; n++)
        {
            element = 1 / ((2*n+1) * pow(x, (2*n+1)));
            sum += element;
            c++;
        }
        if (c < max)
            cout << x << " " << round(sum * 10000) / 10000 << " "
                 << c << " " << round(atanh(x) * 10000)/10000 << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
double arth(double x, double eps)
{
    double res = 1/x, term = 1/x, x2 = 1/(x*x);
    for(int k = 0;abs(term) > eps;++k)
        res += term *= x2*(2*k+1)/(2*k+3);
    return res;
}
```

Не забудьте проверить, что `x>1`.

Comment: `for(int k = 0; abs(term) > eps; res += term *= x2*(1-1/(k++ + 1.5)));` :)

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну, можно и так. Тогда уж внесите все переменные в один цикл. Например, `x2` можно присвоить просто `x`. И у вас скобка после `for` потерялась.

Comment: Спасибо, успел исправить.